# Is $C[a,b]$ dense in $C^1[a,b]$?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

is it true that the space $C[a,b]$ is dense in $C^1[a,b]$? Why or why not?

And in the other direction.
Is it true that the space $C^1[a,b]$ is dense in $C[a,b]$?

Comment: Since $C[a,b]$ is **not** a subset of $C^1[a,b]$, I don't understand your first question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, the *inverse* is true.

$$
C^1[a,b]\subset C[a,b],
$$
and $C^1[a,b]$ is dense in $C[a,b]$. In fact, even the set of polynomials $\mathbb P$ (as a consequence of the theorem of [Stone and Weierstrass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem)) in $[a,b]$, which is a subset $C^1[a,b]$,  is dense in $C[a,b]$.

Answer (score 2):

$C[a,b]$ is not a subset of $C^{1}[a,b]$ so we can not talk about $C[a,b]$ being dense in $C^{1}[a,b]$. The other way is true and it follows by Wierstrass approximation.